# Even if $JRE_HOME is not set java -version is displaying properly

Tags: java, ubuntu, path

I used `sudo apt-get open-jdk7` to install Java on my Ubuntu OS.

When I open a terminal and type `echo $JRE_HOME` it displays nothing. But then I do `java -version` it shows me correct version of OpenJDK. Also when I simply type `java` it works.

Not sure how Ubuntu set the path of java.

Similarly `javac` works but I don't see anything when I say `echo $JAVA_HOME`.

My path does not show java directory path in it.

Where is Ubuntu setting the java path?  Why does Ubuntu not set `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` during installation of OpenJDK?

Answer (score 5):

It's a common misconception that Java somehow requires `JAVA_HOME`, `JRE_HOME` or similar environment variables to be set to work.

In fact the `java` and `javac` (and related) executables don't really care about those variables. They only need to be on the `PATH` (or can be executed via a full path if not on `PATH`) and will find their related install by looking "near itself" (i.e. the executable are usually installed in a known location relative to the JVM files).

There are a few *third party scripts* that use `JAVA_HOME` and/or `JRE_HOME` to find a Java installation (Apache Tomcat is a well-known example for this), but the Java executables themselves don't need those variables.

As to how Ubuntu finds the executables is easy to answer: use `which java` and `which javac` to find out which executables are executed when you type those commands. On Debian-based systems they are usually a series of symlinks through [the alternatives systems](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) that point to the actual executables.

Comment: When I do "echo $PATH" I dont see java path which I see when I do "which javac" !  why ?                                                    Since /usr/bin contains all the executable which path shoudl I set for JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME if I have to. What is default location of java installation in Ubuntu. Any Idea ?

Comment: @user204069: what is the output of `which javac`? As tamas rev's answer mentions it's usually a symlink (possibly multiple levels) to somewhere in `/usr/lib/jvm`.

Answer (score 1):

"Where is ubuntu setting java path?", ubuntu does not set the open-jdk-java-path automatically. 
try

```
find / -name "java"
```

to locate the javac. And write

```
export JRE_HOME="xxx"
```

(where xxx is the base of the open-jdk-jre.)

BTW: You got nothing than trouble with open-jdk. You better use the sun-jdk.

Comment: oracle jdk meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

As many Linux distros, Ubuntu has /etc/alternatives in its paths. If you type:

```
which java
```

Then you'll get

```
/etc/alternatives/java
```

If you type:

```
ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
```

Then you'll get

```
/etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/<your java version>
```

A few mor ls -l -s can help you to get the full picture.